# How do i alter the code below to pad the minute and seconds with a 0 when it is a single digit?

Tags: sql, datepart

The code below is doing just what i want it to do, as far as converting the time to a format that works for my needs.  However, when the minutes and seconds are in the single digit, the format is not looking good.  I would like to adjust the code to pad the minutes and seconds where it is needed.  Any suggestions?  Again, i would like to stay with the existing code as much as possible.
Thank you!

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(CONVERT(CHAR(14), DateTimeRaw, 100), 13, 2)  + ':' + 
CONVERT(nvarchar, DATEPART(minute, DateTimeRaw)) + ':' + 
CONVERT(nvarchar, DATEPART(second, 
DateTimeRaw)) + '.' + CONVERT(nvarchar, DATEPART(ms, DateTimeRaw) / 100)
 + ' ' + CONVERT(nvarchar, CASE WHEN datepart(hour, DateTimeRaw) 
< 12 THEN 'AM' ELSE 'PM' END)   AS AGMPLUSMSTIME
FROM RAW
```

Comment: Use LPAD(string,2,'0'). However I would suggest not using SQL for your string manipulations if possible.

Comment: John you really should use my solution, it solves all your problems and it ie easy to maintain

Answer (score 4):

```
RIGHT('00' + CONVERT(nvarchar, DATEPART(minute, DateTimeRaw)), 2)
```

Basically: concatenate 2 zeroes with your time value, ending up with something like `001`, `0023`, or `0059`, then take the 2 right-most characters, leaving you with `01`, `23`, `59` respectively.

Comment: That makes since!  I am trying it now.

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
select right(stuff(convert(varchar(26), getdate(), 9), 23,2, ' '), 13)
```

Result:

```
 4:35:15:4 PM
```

I used getdate() instead of your field, just as an example